# Website about talk /speech in Chinese

Tags: spoken

What's the website to watch about talk /speech in Chinese, like TEDx ?
What's the keyword to type to find video people do presentation in Chinese in youtube ?

Comment: (中文 or 漢語) + (演講 or 演說)

Answer (score 1):

Youtube is blocked in mainland china. The closest thing is [网易公开课](https://open.163.com/).